# DotNetOpenAuth CTP Source Code Hosted?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Where is the source code hosted?  Git Hub?  I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's on GitHub with the rest of the project.  It's under the master branch.

https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/master

Answer (score 3):

See

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/

**Update**:
OK CTP 3.5 is hosted here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/

Comment: That is the old version.  Where can I find 3.5 online?  That version on goes to 3.4

Comment: Andrew do you have an answer here?

Comment: @giddy this is not the source.  Only the compiled binary as well as samples...  I cannot accept this as the answer.

Comment: I pinged the creator of DotNetOpenAuth [Andrew Arnott](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46926/andrew-arnott)

Comment: Can I join the [ping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977700/fetchdata-using-dotnetopenauth) @AndrewArnott ?