# FetchData using DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, google-api, dotnetopenauth

I have implemented  [*this simple code as described here*](http://www.rtur.net/blog/post/2012/05/23/OpenID-with-ASPNET-Made-Simple) ( vs 2010 , webforms)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
  var response = openid.GetResponse();

  if (response != null && response.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated)
  {
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
  }
}
```

`Click` function :

```
protected void btnGoogle_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
  {
    var request = openid.CreateRequest("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id");
    request.RedirectToProvider();
  }
}
```

**Question #1**

When I click the login  ( via google) it opens [this consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/582wt.jpg)  :

[image]

*But how come it works* ? I thought that I have to create an [*API key*](https://console.developers.google.com/project) in Google developer console in order to allow people to login. ( *like I did here with other app of myne->*)

[image]

Obviously I didn't create *any* "`localhost`" app. so how does it still works ? (again it's a demo I've downloaded from the internet).

**Question #2**

Once I have [a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG0fZ.jpg) :

[image]

How can I fetch user data ? ( email for example) *{the article doesn't mention it}*

*nb DotNetOpenAuth ver 3.4.6.10357*

Comment: In your session are you logged in to your google account 'via the browser'? - "If user logged into Gmail, he is already authenticated and Google will send back response verifying user’s credentials.", "Again we use relying party object, this time to create response. If response is authenticated by Google – we know who user is... it only means that we know ID that Google assigns to this person"

Comment: @PaulZahra what about getting the email via this id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line works because it uses [openId](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) and not OAuth2.  Open id is old school before [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).

You should also be aware of:

> Important: Google has deprecated OpenID 2.0 and will shut it down
>   after a migration period. If your app uses OpenID 2.0, the userinfo
>   endpoint, or OAuth 2.0 login (early version), you should migrate your
>   app by the deadlines given in the migration timetable.

Because OpenId has been depreciated and will be shutdown before April 20, 2015 I wouldn't recommend developing with it.

To answer the question that request doesn't require a client id because its opened and not Oauth2 only oauth2 requires a client id.

Recommend: [Google APIs Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/)
Tutorial: [Google Oauth2 C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/)

Comment: Regarding my bottom pic , how can/could i fetch email via this url ?

Comment: @dalm. yes. something I can save to db : abc@aaa.com is its email

Comment: Update after playing with it for 4 hours I have decided that Oauth2dotnet library is useless (I don't think it supports oauth2, but I cant prove that).  If you need help making the calls manually let me know.

Comment: @Tha's why I suggest you to build a library - you and me